# How do I make an attributed string using Swift?

Tags: fonts, uilabel, swift, nsattributedstring

I am trying to make a simple Coffee Calculator. I need to display the amount of coffee in grams. The "g" symbol for grams needs to be attached to my UILabel that I am using to display the amount. The numbers in the UILabel are changing dynamically with user input just fine, but I need to add a lower case "g" on the end of the string that is formatted differently from the  updating numbers. The "g" needs to be attached to the numbers so that as the number size and position changes, the "g" "moves" with the numbers. I'm sure this problem has been solved before so a link in the right direction would be helpful as I've googled my little heart out.

I've searched through the documentation for an attributed string and I even downloded an "Attributed String Creator" from the app store, but the resulting code is in Objective-C and I am using Swift. What would be awesome, and probably helpful to other developers learning this language, is a clear example of creating a custom font with custom attributes using an attributed string in Swift. The documentation for this is very confusing as there is not a very clear path on how to do so. My plan is to create the attributed string and add it to the end of my coffeeAmount string.

```
var coffeeAmount: String = calculatedCoffee + attributedText
```

Where calculatedCoffee is an Int converted to a string and "attributedText" is the lowercase "g" with customized font that I am trying to create. Maybe I'm going about this the wrong way. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1090):

[image]

*This answer has been updated for Swift 4.2.*

## Quick Reference

The general form for making and setting an attributed string is like this. You can find other common options below.

```
// create attributed string
let myString = "Swift Attributed String"
let myAttribute = [ NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.blue ]
let myAttrString = NSAttributedString(string: myString, attributes: myAttribute) 

// set attributed text on a UILabel
myLabel.attributedText = myAttrString
```

[image: Text Color]

```
let myAttribute = [ NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.blue ]
```

[image: Background Color]

```
let myAttribute = [ NSAttributedString.Key.backgroundColor: UIColor.yellow ]
```

[image: Font]

```
let myAttribute = [ NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont(name: "Chalkduster", size: 18.0)! ]
```

[image]

```
let myAttribute = [ NSAttributedString.Key.underlineStyle: NSUnderlineStyle.single.rawValue ]
```

[image]

```
let myShadow = NSShadow()
myShadow.shadowBlurRadius = 3
myShadow.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 3, height: 3)
myShadow.shadowColor = UIColor.gray

let myAttribute = [ NSAttributedString.Key.shadow: myShadow ]
```

The rest of this post gives more detail for those who are interested.

---

## Attributes

String attributes are just a dictionary in the form of `[NSAttributedString.Key: Any]`, where `NSAttributedString.Key` is the key name of the attribute and `Any` is the value of some Type. The value could be a font, a color, an integer, or something else. There are many standard attributes in Swift that have already been predefined. For example:

- key name: `NSAttributedString.Key.font`, value: a `UIFont`
- key name: `NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor`, value: a `UIColor`
- key name: `NSAttributedString.Key.link`, value: an `NSURL` or `NSString`

There are many others. See [this link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/AttributedStrings/Articles/standardAttributes.html) for more. You can even make your own custom attributes like:

- key name: `NSAttributedString.Key.myName`, value: some Type.
  if you make an [extension](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33942483/3681880):

  ```
  extension NSAttributedString.Key {
      static let myName = NSAttributedString.Key(rawValue: "myCustomAttributeKey")
  }
  ```

#### Creating attributes in Swift

You can declare attributes just like declaring any other dictionary.

```
// single attributes declared one at a time
let singleAttribute1 = [ NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.green ]
let singleAttribute2 = [ NSAttributedString.Key.backgroundColor: UIColor.yellow ]
let singleAttribute3 = [ NSAttributedString.Key.underlineStyle: NSUnderlineStyle.double.rawValue ]

// multiple attributes declared at once
let multipleAttributes: [NSAttributedString.Key : Any] = [
    NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.green,
    NSAttributedString.Key.backgroundColor: UIColor.yellow,
    NSAttributedString.Key.underlineStyle: NSUnderlineStyle.double.rawValue ]

// custom attribute
let customAttribute = [ NSAttributedString.Key.myName: "Some value" ]
```

Note the `rawValue` that was needed for the underline style value.

Because attributes are just Dictionaries, you can also create them by making an empty Dictionary and then adding key-value pairs to it. If the value will contain multiple types, then you have to use [`Any`](https://craiggrummitt.wordpress.com/2016/09/16/any-vs-anyobject-vs-nsobject-in-swift-3/) as the type. Here is the `multipleAttributes` example from above, recreated in this fashion:

```
var multipleAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key : Any]()
multipleAttributes[NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor] = UIColor.green
multipleAttributes[NSAttributedString.Key.backgroundColor] = UIColor.yellow
multipleAttributes[NSAttributedString.Key.underlineStyle] = NSUnderlineStyle.double.rawValue
```

## Attributed Strings

Now that you understand attributes, you can make attributed strings.

**Initialization**

There are a few ways to create attributed strings. If you just need a read-only string you can use `NSAttributedString`. Here are some ways to initialize it:

```
// Initialize with a string only
let attrString1 = NSAttributedString(string: "Hello.")

// Initialize with a string and inline attribute(s)
let attrString2 = NSAttributedString(string: "Hello.", attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.myName: "A value"])

// Initialize with a string and separately declared attribute(s)
let myAttributes1 = [ NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.green ]
let attrString3 = NSAttributedString(string: "Hello.", attributes: myAttributes1)
```

If you will need to change the attributes or the string content later, you should use `NSMutableAttributedString`. The declarations are very similar:

```
// Create a blank attributed string
let mutableAttrString1 = NSMutableAttributedString()

// Initialize with a string only
let mutableAttrString2 = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Hello.")

// Initialize with a string and inline attribute(s)
let mutableAttrString3 = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Hello.", attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.myName: "A value"])

// Initialize with a string and separately declared attribute(s)
let myAttributes2 = [ NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.green ]
let mutableAttrString4 = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Hello.", attributes: myAttributes2)
```

## Changing an Attributed String

As an example, let's create the attributed string at the top of this post.

First create an `NSMutableAttributedString` with a new font attribute.

```
let myAttribute = [ NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont(name: "Chalkduster", size: 18.0)! ]
let myString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Swift", attributes: myAttribute )
```

If you are working along, set the attributed string to a `UITextView` (or `UILabel`) like this:

```
textView.attributedText = myString
```

You *don't* use `textView.text`.

Here is the result:

[image]

Then append another attributed string that doesn't have any attributes set. (Notice that even though I used `let` to declare `myString` above, I can still modify it because it is an `NSMutableAttributedString`. This seems rather unSwiftlike to me and I wouldn't be surprised if this changes in the future. Leave me a comment when that happens.)

```
let attrString = NSAttributedString(string: " Attributed Strings")
myString.append(attrString)
```

[image]

Next we'll just select the "Strings" word, which starts at index `17` and has a length of `7`. Notice that this is an `NSRange` and not a Swift `Range`. (See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35193481/3681880) for more about Ranges.) The `addAttribute` method lets us put the attribute key name in the first spot, the attribute value in the second spot, and the range in the third spot.

```
var myRange = NSRange(location: 17, length: 7) // range starting at location 17 with a lenth of 7: "Strings"
myString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor, value: UIColor.red, range: myRange)
```

[image]

Finally, let's add a background color. For variety, let's use the `addAttributes` method (note the `s`). I could add multiple attributes at once with this method, but I will just add one again.

```
myRange = NSRange(location: 3, length: 17)
let anotherAttribute = [ NSAttributedString.Key.backgroundColor: UIColor.yellow ]
myString.addAttributes(anotherAttribute, range: myRange)
```

[image]

Notice that the attributes are overlapping in some places. Adding an attribute doesn't overwrite an attribute that is already there.

## Related

- [How to change the text of an `NSMutableAttributedString` but keep the attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34628596/3681880)

## Further Reading

- [How to retrieve the attributes from a tap location](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32262426/3681880)
- [Attributed String Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/AttributedStrings/AttributedStrings.html) (very informative but unfortunately only in Objective-C)

Comment: Note that you can combine several styles for underlining, e.g. `NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName: NSUnderlineStyle.StyleSingle.rawValue | NSUnderlineStyle.PatternDot.rawValue`

Comment: You can not use appendAttributedString on NSAttributedString it has to be on NSMutableAttributedString, can you update your answer to reflect this?

Comment: **1)** Super thanks for your answer. **2)** I would suggest that you place `textView.atrributedtText = myString` or `myLabel.attributedText = myString` at the **beginning** of your answer. As a newbie I was just doing `myLabel.text` and didn't think I needed to go through *all* your answer.**3)** Does this mean that you can only have either `attributedText` or `text` as having them both would be meaningless? **4)** I recommend that you also incorporate `lineSpacing` example like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31642194/5175709) in your answer as it's *very* useful. **5)** ачаар дахин

Comment: The difference between append and add was confusing first. `appendAttributedString` is like 'String concatenation'. `addAttribute` is adding a new attribute to your string.

Comment: `Value of type 'String' has no member 'addAttribute'` - `Value of type 'NSAttributedString' has no member 'addAttribute'` - me confused

Comment: @Daniel, `addAttribute` is a method of `NSMutableAttributedString`. You are right that you can't use it with `String` or `NSAttributedString`. (Check the `myString` definition in the **Changing an Attributed String** section of this post. I think I threw you off because I also used `myString` for the variable name in the first part of the post where it was an `NSAttributedString`.)

Answer (score 118):

Swift uses the same `NSMutableAttributedString` that Obj-C does. You instantiate it by passing in the calculated value as a string:

```
var attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string:"\(calculatedCoffee)")
```

Now create the attributed `g` string (heh). **Note:** `UIFont.systemFontOfSize(_)` is now a failable initializer, so it has to be unwrapped before you can use it:

```
var attrs = [NSFontAttributeName : UIFont.systemFontOfSize(19.0)!]
var gString = NSMutableAttributedString(string:"g", attributes:attrs)
```

And then append it:

```
attributedString.appendAttributedString(gString)
```

You can then set the UILabel to display the NSAttributedString like this:

```
myLabel.attributedText = attributedString
```

Comment: `//Part 1 Set Up The Lower Case g
var coffeeText = NSMutableAttributedString(string:"\(calculateCoffee())")

//Part 2 set the font attributes for the lower case g
var coffeeTypeFaceAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName : UIFont.systemFontOfSize(18)]

//Part 3 create the "g" character and give it the attributes
var coffeeG = NSMutableAttributedString(string:"g", attributes:coffeeTypeFaceAttributes)`

When I set my UILabel.text = coffeeText I get an error "NSMutableAttributedString is not convertable to 'String'. Is there a way to make the UILabel accept NSMutableAttributedString?

Comment: When you have an attributed string, you need to set the label's attributedText property instead of its text property.

Comment: This worked properly and my lower case "g" is now appeneding to the end of my coffee amount text

Comment: For some reason I get an error "extra argument in call" on my line with the NSAttributedString. This only happens when I switch the UIFont.systemFontOfSize(18) to UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 20). Any ideas?

Comment: UIFont(name: size:) is a failable initialiser and may return nil. You can either explicitly unwrap it by adding ! on the end or bind it to a variable with an if/let statement before you insert it into the dictionary.

Comment: Plus 1 for the g string (heh). Laughed out loud on the floor at work

Answer (score 23):

I would highly recommend using a library for attributed strings. It makes it *much* easier when you want, for example, one string with four different colors and four different fonts.  [Here is my favorite.](https://github.com/eddiekaiger/SwiftyAttributes) It is called SwiftyAttributes

If you wanted to make a string with four different colors and different fonts using SwiftyAttributes:

```
let magenta = "Hello ".withAttributes([
    .textColor(.magenta),
    .font(.systemFont(ofSize: 15.0))
    ])
let cyan = "Sir ".withAttributes([
    .textColor(.cyan),
    .font(.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 15.0))
    ])
let green = "Lancelot".withAttributes([
    .textColor(.green),
    .font(.italicSystemFont(ofSize: 15.0))

    ])
let blue = "!".withAttributes([
    .textColor(.blue),
    .font(.preferredFont(forTextStyle: UIFontTextStyle.headline))

    ])
let finalString = magenta + cyan + green + blue
```

`finalString` would show as

[image: Shows as image]

Answer (score 22):

**Swift 5**

```swift
let attrStri = NSMutableAttributedString.init(string:"This is red")
let nsRange = NSString(string: "This is red")
        .range(of: "red", options: String.CompareOptions.caseInsensitive)
attrStri.addAttributes([
    NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : UIColor.red,
    NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.init(name: "PTSans-Regular", size: 15.0) as Any
], range: nsRange)
self.label.attributedText = attrStri
```

[image]

Answer (score 21):

**Xcode 6 version**:

```
let attriString = NSAttributedString(string:"attriString", attributes:
[NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.lightGrayColor(), 
            NSFontAttributeName: AttriFont])
```

**Xcode 9.3 version**:

```
let attriString = NSAttributedString(string:"attriString", attributes:
[NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.lightGray, 
            NSAttributedStringKey.font: AttriFont])
```

**Xcode 10, iOS 12, Swift 4**:

```
let attriString = NSAttributedString(string:"attriString", attributes:
[NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.lightGray, 
            NSAttributedString.Key.font: AttriFont])
```

Answer (score 20):

**Swift 4:**

```
let attributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Bold", size: 17)!, 
                  NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
```

Comment: it does not compile `Type 'NSAttributedStringKey' (aka 'NSString') has no member 'font'`

Comment: I've just tried it in newest XCode (10 beta 6) and it does compile, are you sure you're using Swift 4?

Comment: I am using Swift 3

Comment: Well that's the issue, my answer has bold title "Swift 4", I highly suggest you update to Swift 4

Comment: @bibscy you can use NSAttributedString.Key.***

Answer (score 15):

Swift: xcode 6.1

```
    let font:UIFont? = UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 12.0)

    let attrString = NSAttributedString(
        string: titleData,
        attributes: NSDictionary(
            object: font!,
            forKey: NSFontAttributeName))
```

Answer (score 14):

### Details

- Swift 5.2, Xcode 11.4 (11E146)

### Solution

```
protocol AttributedStringComponent {
    var text: String { get }
    func getAttributes() -> [NSAttributedString.Key: Any]?
}

// MARK: String extensions

extension String: AttributedStringComponent {
    var text: String { self }
    func getAttributes() -> [NSAttributedString.Key: Any]? { return nil }
}

extension String {
    func toAttributed(with attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any]?) -> NSAttributedString {
        .init(string: self, attributes: attributes)
    }
}

// MARK: NSAttributedString extensions

extension NSAttributedString: AttributedStringComponent {
    var text: String { string }

    func getAttributes() -> [Key: Any]? {
        if string.isEmpty { return nil }
        var range = NSRange(location: 0, length: string.count)
        return attributes(at: 0, effectiveRange: &range)
    }
}

extension NSAttributedString {

    convenience init?(from attributedStringComponents: [AttributedStringComponent],
                      defaultAttributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any],
                      joinedSeparator: String = " ") {
        switch attributedStringComponents.count {
        case 0: return nil
        default:
            var joinedString = ""
            typealias SttributedStringComponentDescriptor = ([NSAttributedString.Key: Any], NSRange)
            let sttributedStringComponents = attributedStringComponents.enumerated().flatMap { (index, component) -> [SttributedStringComponentDescriptor] in
                var components = [SttributedStringComponentDescriptor]()
                if index != 0 {
                    components.append((defaultAttributes,
                                       NSRange(location: joinedString.count, length: joinedSeparator.count)))
                    joinedString += joinedSeparator
                }
                components.append((component.getAttributes() ?? defaultAttributes,
                                   NSRange(location: joinedString.count, length: component.text.count)))
                joinedString += component.text
                return components
            }

            let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: joinedString)
            sttributedStringComponents.forEach { attributedString.addAttributes($0, range: $1) }
            self.init(attributedString: attributedString)
        }
    }
}
```

### Usage

```
let defaultAttributes = [
    .font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16, weight: .regular),
    .foregroundColor: UIColor.blue
] as [NSAttributedString.Key : Any]

let marketingAttributes = [
    .font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20.0, weight: .bold),
    .foregroundColor: UIColor.black
] as [NSAttributedString.Key : Any]

let attributedStringComponents = [
    "pay for",
    NSAttributedString(string: "one",
                       attributes: marketingAttributes),
    "and get",
    "three!\n".toAttributed(with: marketingAttributes),
    "Only today!".toAttributed(with: [
        .font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16.0, weight: .bold),
        .foregroundColor: UIColor.red
    ])
] as [AttributedStringComponent]
let attributedText = NSAttributedString(from: attributedStringComponents, defaultAttributes: defaultAttributes)
```

### Full Example

> do not forget to **paste the solution code here**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    private weak var label: UILabel!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let label = UILabel(frame: .init(x: 40, y: 40, width: 300, height: 80))
        label.numberOfLines = 2
        view.addSubview(label)
        self.label = label

        let defaultAttributes = [
            .font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16, weight: .regular),
            .foregroundColor: UIColor.blue
        ] as [NSAttributedString.Key : Any]

        let marketingAttributes = [
            .font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20.0, weight: .bold),
            .foregroundColor: UIColor.black
        ] as [NSAttributedString.Key : Any]

        let attributedStringComponents = [
            "pay for",
            NSAttributedString(string: "one",
                               attributes: marketingAttributes),
            "and get",
            "three!\n".toAttributed(with: marketingAttributes),
            "Only today!".toAttributed(with: [
                .font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16.0, weight: .bold),
                .foregroundColor: UIColor.red
            ])
        ] as [AttributedStringComponent]
        label.attributedText = NSAttributedString(from: attributedStringComponents, defaultAttributes: defaultAttributes)
        label.textAlignment = .center
    }
}
```

### Result

[image]

Answer (score 11):

***Swift 2.0***

**Here is a sample:**

```
let newsString: NSMutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Tap here to read the latest Football News.")
newsString.addAttributes([NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName: NSUnderlineStyle.StyleDouble.rawValue], range: NSMakeRange(4, 4))
sampleLabel.attributedText = newsString.copy() as? NSAttributedString
```

**Swift 5.x**

```
let newsString: NSMutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Tap here to read the latest Football News.")
newsString.addAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.underlineStyle: NSUnderlineStyle.double.rawValue], range: NSMakeRange(4, 4))
sampleLabel.attributedText = newsString.copy() as? NSAttributedString
```

OR

```
let stringAttributes = [
    NSFontAttributeName : UIFont(name: "Helvetica Neue", size: 17.0)!,
    NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName : 1,
    NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.orangeColor(),
    NSTextEffectAttributeName : NSTextEffectLetterpressStyle,
    NSStrokeWidthAttributeName : 2.0]
let atrributedString = NSAttributedString(string: "Sample String: Attributed", attributes: stringAttributes)
sampleLabel.attributedText = atrributedString
```

Answer (score 11):

The best way to approach Attributed Strings on iOS is by using the built-in Attributed Text editor in the interface builder and avoid uneccessary hardcoding NSAtrributedStringKeys in your source files.

You can later dynamically replace  placehoderls at runtime by using this extension:

```swift
extension NSAttributedString {
    func replacing(placeholder:String, with valueString:String) -> NSAttributedString {

        if let range = self.string.range(of:placeholder) {
            let nsRange = NSRange(range,in:valueString)
            let mutableText = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: self)
            mutableText.replaceCharacters(in: nsRange, with: valueString)
            return mutableText as NSAttributedString
        }
        return self
    }
}
```

Add a storyboard label with attributed text looking like this.

[image]

Then you simply update the value each time you need like this:

```swift
label.attributedText = initalAttributedString.replacing(placeholder: "<price>", with: newValue)
```

Make sure to save into initalAttributedString the original value.

You can better understand this approach by reading this article:
https://medium.com/mobile-appetite/text-attributes-on-ios-the-effortless-approach-ff086588173e

Comment: This was really helpful for my case, where I had a Storyboard and just wanted to add bold to part of the string in a label. Much simpler than setting up all of the attributes manually.

Comment: This extension used to work for me perfectly, but in Xcode 11 it crashed my app at the `let nsRange = NSRange(range,in:valueString)` line.

Answer (score 9):

I created an online tool that is going to solve your problem! You can write your string and apply styles graphically and the tool gives you objective-c and swift code to generate that string.

Also is open source so feel free to extend it and send PRs.

[Transformer Tool](https://andresinaka.github.io/Transformer/)

[Github](https://github.com/andresinaka/transformer)

[image]

Comment: Not working for me. It just wraps everything in brackets without applying any style.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.! Who remembers the `NSAttributedString ` Anyway ? #Bookmarked

Answer (score 8):

Works well in beta 6

```
let attrString = NSAttributedString(
    string: "title-title-title",
    attributes: NSDictionary(
       object: NSFont(name: "Arial", size: 12.0), 
       forKey: NSFontAttributeName))
```

Answer (score 7):

**Swift 5 and above**

```
   let attributedString = NSAttributedString(string:"targetString",
                                   attributes:[NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.lightGray,
                                               NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 18.0) as Any])
```

Answer (score 6):

**Swift 3,4,5**

**Use below code for Text Color, Font, Background Color and Underline/Un derline Color**

```
    let text = "swift is language"
    let attributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.red, NSAttributedString.Key.backgroundColor: UIColor.blue,NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 25.0),NSAttributedString.Key.underlineColor: UIColor.white,NSAttributedString.Key.underlineStyle: NSUnderlineStyle.single.rawValue] as [NSAttributedString.Key : Any]
        
    let textAttribute = NSAttributedString(string: text, attributes: attributes)
    swiftLabel1.attributedText = textAttribute
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

```
func decorateText(sub:String, des:String)->NSAttributedString{
    let textAttributesOne = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.darkText, NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont(name: "PTSans-Bold", size: 17.0)!]
    let textAttributesTwo = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.black, NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont(name: "PTSans-Regular", size: 14.0)!]

    let textPartOne = NSMutableAttributedString(string: sub, attributes: textAttributesOne)
    let textPartTwo = NSMutableAttributedString(string: des, attributes: textAttributesTwo)

    let textCombination = NSMutableAttributedString()
    textCombination.append(textPartOne)
    textCombination.append(textPartTwo)
    return textCombination
}
```

//Implementation

```
cell.lblFrom.attributedText = decorateText(sub: sender!, des: " - \(convertDateFormatShort3(myDateString: datetime!))")
```

Answer (score 4):

**Swift 4**

```
let attributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.font : UIFont(name: CustomFont.NAME_REGULAR.rawValue, size: CustomFontSize.SURVEY_FORM_LABEL_SIZE.rawValue)!]

let attributedString : NSAttributedString = NSAttributedString(string: messageString, attributes: attributes)
```

You need to remove the raw value in swift 4

Answer (score 4):

Use this sample code. This is very short code to achieve your requirement. This is working for me.

```
let attributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.font : UIFont(name: CustomFont.NAME_REGULAR.rawValue, size: CustomFontSize.SURVEY_FORM_LABEL_SIZE.rawValue)!]

let attributedString : NSAttributedString = NSAttributedString(string: messageString, attributes: attributes)
```

Answer (score 3):

For me above solutions didn't work when setting a specific color or property.

This did work:

```
let attributes = [
    NSFontAttributeName : UIFont(name: "Helvetica Neue", size: 12.0)!,
    NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName : 1,
    NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.darkGrayColor(),
    NSTextEffectAttributeName : NSTextEffectLetterpressStyle,
    NSStrokeWidthAttributeName : 3.0]

var atriString = NSAttributedString(string: "My Attributed String", attributes: attributes)
```

Answer (score 3):

Swift 2.1 - Xcode 7

```
let labelFont = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Bold", size: 18)
let attributes :[String:AnyObject] = [NSFontAttributeName : labelFont!]
let attrString = NSAttributedString(string:"foo", attributes: attributes)
myLabel.attributedText = attrString
```

Comment: What changes were made between Swift 2.0 and 2.1?

Answer (score 3):

I did a function that takes **array of strings** and returns **attributed string** with the attributes you give.

```
func createAttributedString(stringArray: [String], attributedPart: Int, attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any]) -> NSMutableAttributedString? {
    let finalString = NSMutableAttributedString()
    for i in 0 ..< stringArray.count {
        var attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: stringArray[i], attributes: nil)
        if i == attributedPart {
            attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: attributedString.string, attributes: attributes)
            finalString.append(attributedString)
        } else {
            finalString.append(attributedString)
        }
    }
    return finalString
}
```

In the example above you specify what part of string you want to get attributed with **attributedPart: Int**

And then you give the attributes for it with
**attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any]**

### USE EXAMPLE

```
if let attributedString = createAttributedString(stringArray: ["Hello ", "how ", " are you?"], attributedPart: 2, attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.systemYellow]) {
      myLabel.attributedText = attributedString
}
```

Will do:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
extension UILabel{
    func setSubTextColor(pSubString : String, pColor : UIColor){    
        let attributedString: NSMutableAttributedString = self.attributedText != nil ? NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: self.attributedText!) : NSMutableAttributedString(string: self.text!);

        let range = attributedString.mutableString.range(of: pSubString, options:NSString.CompareOptions.caseInsensitive)
        if range.location != NSNotFound {
            attributedString.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: pColor, range: range);
        }
        self.attributedText = attributedString
    }
}
```

Comment: cell.IBLabelGuestAppointmentTime.text = "\n\nGuest1\n8:00 am\n\nGuest2\n9:00Am\n\n"
        cell.IBLabelGuestAppointmentTime.setSubTextColor(pSubString: "Guest1", pColor: UIColor.white)
        cell.IBLabelGuestAppointmentTime.setSubTextColor(pSubString: "Guest2", pColor: UIColor.red)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please format your code, and add some explanation/context to your answer. See: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 2):

The attributes can be setting directly in swift 3...

```
    let attributes = NSAttributedString(string: "String", attributes: [NSFontAttributeName : UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-Medium", size: 30)!,
         NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor .white,
         NSTextEffectAttributeName : NSTextEffectLetterpressStyle])
```

Then use the variable in any class with attributes

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 4.2**

```
extension UILabel {

    func boldSubstring(_ substr: String) {
        guard substr.isEmpty == false,
            let text = attributedText,
            let range = text.string.range(of: substr, options: .caseInsensitive) else {
                return
        }
        let attr = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: text)
        let start = text.string.distance(from: text.string.startIndex, to: range.lowerBound)
        let length = text.string.distance(from: range.lowerBound, to: range.upperBound)
        attr.addAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: self.font.pointSize)],
                           range: NSMakeRange(start, length))
        attributedText = attr
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not simply range.count for the length?

Answer (score 1):

```
 let attrString = NSAttributedString (
            string: "title-title-title",
            attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.black])
```

Answer (score 1):

It will be really easy to solve your problem with the library I created. It is called Atributika.

```
let calculatedCoffee: Int = 768
let g = Style("g").font(.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 12)).foregroundColor(.red)
let all = Style.font(.systemFont(ofSize: 12))

let str = "\(calculatedCoffee)<g>g</g>".style(tags: g)
    .styleAll(all)
    .attributedString

label.attributedText = str
```

[image: 768g]

You can find it here https://github.com/psharanda/Atributika

Answer (score 1):

[Swifter Swift](https://github.com/SwifterSwift/SwifterSwift) has a pretty sweet way to do this without any work really. Just provide the pattern that should be matched and what attributes to apply to it. They're great for a lot of things check them out.

````
``` Swift
let defaultGenreText = NSAttributedString(string: "Select Genre - Required")
let redGenreText = defaultGenreText.applying(attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : UIColor.red], toRangesMatching: "Required")
``
````

If you have multiple places where this would be applied and you only want it to happen for specific instances then this method wouldn't work.

You can do this in one step, just easier to read when separated.

Answer (score 0):

Swift 4.x

```
let attr = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName:self.configuration.settingsColor, NSFontAttributeName: self.configuration.settingsFont]

let title = NSAttributedString(string: self.configuration.settingsTitle,
                               attributes: attr)
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 3.0 
// create attributed string

Define attributes like

```
let attributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.font : UIFont.init(name: "Avenir-Medium", size: 13.0)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Please consider using [Prestyler](https://github.com/kruil/Prestyler)

```
import Prestyler
...
Prestyle.defineRule("$", UIColor.red)
label.attributedText = "\(calculatedCoffee) $g$".prestyled()
```

Answer (score 0):

Objective-C 2.0 example:

```objectivec
myUILabel.text = @"€ 60,00";
NSMutableAttributedString *amountText = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:myUILabel.text];

//Add attributes you are looking for
NSDictionary *dictionaryOfAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                        [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12],NSFontAttributeName,
                                        [UIColor grayColor],NSForegroundColorAttributeName,
                                        nil];

//Will gray color and resize the € symbol
[amountText setAttributes:dictionaryOfAttributes range:NSMakeRange(0, 1)];
myUILabel.attributedText = amountText;
```

Answer (score -5):

```
extension String {
//MARK: Getting customized string
struct StringAttribute {
    var fontName = "HelveticaNeue-Bold"
    var fontSize: CGFloat?
    var initialIndexOftheText = 0
    var lastIndexOftheText: Int?
    var textColor: UIColor = .black
    var backGroundColor: UIColor = .clear
    var underLineStyle: NSUnderlineStyle = .styleNone
    var textShadow: TextShadow = TextShadow()

    var fontOfText: UIFont {
        if let font = UIFont(name: fontName, size: fontSize!) {
            return font
        } else {
            return UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Bold", size: fontSize!)!
        }
    }

    struct TextShadow {
        var shadowBlurRadius = 0
        var shadowOffsetSize = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)
        var shadowColor: UIColor = .clear
    }
}
func getFontifiedText(partOfTheStringNeedToConvert partTexts: [StringAttribute]) -> NSAttributedString {
    let fontChangedtext = NSMutableAttributedString(string: self, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Bold", size: (partTexts.first?.fontSize)!)!])
    for eachPartText in partTexts {
        let lastIndex = eachPartText.lastIndexOftheText ?? self.count
        let attrs = [NSFontAttributeName : eachPartText.fontOfText, NSForegroundColorAttributeName: eachPartText.textColor, NSBackgroundColorAttributeName: eachPartText.backGroundColor, NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName: eachPartText.underLineStyle, NSShadowAttributeName: eachPartText.textShadow ] as [String : Any]
        let range = NSRange(location: eachPartText.initialIndexOftheText, length: lastIndex - eachPartText.initialIndexOftheText)
        fontChangedtext.addAttributes(attrs, range: range)
    }
    return fontChangedtext
}
```

}

//Use it like below

```
    let someAttributedText = "Some   Text".getFontifiedText(partOfTheStringNeedToConvert: <#T##[String.StringAttribute]#>)
```

Comment: this answer tells you everything you need to know except how to make an attributed string in swift.