# What is UTF-8 character for "previous arrow", same as system back in UINavigationItem?

Tags: ios, utf-8

I just couldn't find utf-8 encoding for character like following:

[image]

I think that it is quite possible to create this in code, as a composed character from two dashes: `/` and `\`, but I do not know what characters to compose.

Answer (score 2):

Possibly [U+2039](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2039/index.htm).

```
print("\u{2039}") // ‹
```

Or [U+276E](http://www.charbase.com/276e-unicode-heavy-left-pointing-angle-quotation-mark-ornament).

```
print("\u{276E}") // ❮
```

---

I'm not certain if this will work for a navigation item, but you could make use of `NSAttributedString` to have string with different sizes of the substrings within it. This is described in detail in this great answer:

- [How do I make an attributed string using Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24666515/how-do-i-make-an-attributed-string-using-swift)

As an example for your case:

```
let myAttributeBack = [ NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-UltraLight", size: 30.0)!]
let attrString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "\u{276E} ", attributes: myAttributeBack)

let myAttributeText = [ NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-UltraLight", size: 15.0)!]
let backString = NSAttributedString(string: "back", attributes: myAttributeText)

attrString.appendAttributedString(backString)

myLabel.attributedText = attrString
```

However, as you write below, perhaps it's not possible to use attributed strings for title of a navigation bar item. Then I'd assume that the navigation bar example you showed above simply contains an image with the back bracket and a string "back" for the title text.

Comment: the first one is correct, but too small. Can I increase the size somehow? I need to assign it this way: `navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.title = "\u{2039}Back"`. `attributedTitle` doesn't work.

Comment: Hmm you should be able to increase the size of only parts of a text field (attributed strings). however I'm not sure it will work with the navigation button. 1 min (see also if possibly U+276E can, added into answer). In your example above, it looks as if the "<" is of quite larger font than the text.

Comment: Is there a third one slightly bigger than the previous one?:)

Comment: I haven't been able to find one, but I think you want to use one of the two above and use `NSAttributedString`. Trying something out, a few mins :)

Comment: I think this is impossible to assign `NSAttributedString` to the `title` of `leftBarButtonItem`.

Comment: @BartłomiejSemańczyk I see, then it's gonna be tricky... Perhaps the above example is using an image + text?

Comment: Alternatively create your own custom UILabel that the navigation bar makes use of. The UILabel can make use of attributed strings.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe U+003C

```
print("\u{003C}") // <
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it this:

```
〈
```

The code is U+276C.
see https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E3%80%88

Comment: No, the angle is too wide.