# how to Segue to uitextview from uitableview in swift and use nsattributedtext property

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, segue, uitextviewdelegate

I am developing an IOS app using swift language in which I want to segue from uitableview's row  to uitextview to show some text and I want to use attributed text property of uitextview but its not working.How to do that?

Comment: A segue takes you from one UIViewController to another. You can have a UITableView inside of a viewController where the viewController is the delegate of the tableView. It sounds like you are not properly describing what you want. Edit your question to include what you have in the didSelectRow delegate method. Also describe in plain words what you want to happen when you select a row. Do you leave and go to a new page or does something on that page change?

Comment: i am using static rows and when the row is selected it goes to a new view controller where I used a uitextview to show some text.I only wants to use attributes for that text to be displayed by programming since the text changes which each different row so I can not place text in the text attribute of uitextview at storyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you can't segue to a `UITextView`; you can segue only to another view *controller*. But maybe you meant to say that your segue goes to a view controller with a `UITextView` in it. If so, then control-drag a segue from your table view cell to the other view controller, and give the segue an identifier. Then, in your table view controller, implement:

```
func prepareForSegue(_ segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "the-segue-id-that-you-put-in-your-storyboard" {
        // Cast your destination view controller to the specific type
        if let destinationVC = segue.destination as? <your-view-controller-type> {
            destinationVC.textView.attributedText = <your-string>
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes you are right I want the same thing but it will be more helpful if you tell how to write attributed string for the last line you have written since I can only assign a string of type NSattributedstring to destinationvc.textview.attributedText.

Comment: It's funny you should ask, since I have [another StackOverflow answer that discusses just that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24666515/how-do-i-make-an-attributed-string-using-swift/24666710#24666710)...

Comment: i am facing error at the line destinationvc.textview.attributedText. The error is " fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value".

Comment: Make sure that your `textView`'s outlet is properly set to the text view instance in your storyboard.

Comment: its set properly when i use destinationvc.text = "something" the text is shown but when I used destinationvc.textview.text = "something" it shows this error.

Comment: So your destination view controller must have a `text` attribute that sets the text view's text.

Comment: Yeah got that and thanks for great help.Can I PM you when I need help in future?please give me your facebook id or something where i can.It will be so kind of you.