# How can I set a custom color and font size for the title of an NSButton?(in OS X NOT iOS)

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, swift2, xcode7

For example consider I have a button named Button and its title is "Hello" . How can I make the title red colored with a font size of 35?
Thanks for all your answers in advance!

Comment: Have you looked at NSAttributedString?

Comment: Yes, that makes it red, but resets the font size I set in the interface builder.(I don't know how to set the font size using NSAttributedString)

Comment: Have you googled it? It's pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**SOLUTION:**

```
    button.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Title", attributes: [ NSForegroundColorAttributeName : NSColor.redColor(),  NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Chalkduster", size: 35.0)!])
```

Comment: So what about the color?

Comment: @S.Shahsiah Answer edited.

Comment: When I use attributedTitle, it resets the font size to 15 no matter what size I indicate before it

Comment: @S.Shahsiah And after it ?

Comment: The color will be set but the font size won't. And I did google it, but I didn't find a way to set BOTH color and font size

Comment: @S.Shahsiah http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24666515/how-do-i-make-an-attributed-string-using-swift

Comment: Thank you very much. That did it!

Comment: @S.Shahsiah Happy to help ! Btw, there is someone who answered one of your questions with 6 upvotes whose answer you haven't yet accepted ! (it's not me)

Comment: Oh, I just did it.

Comment: @S.Shahsiah Great ! It would have been unfair for SpacyRicochet never to get his answer accepted :)

Comment: By the way, should I mark this question as being different than "How do I make an attributed string using Swift?" or not

Comment: @S.Shahsiah In my opinion, they are the same.