# Can't apply line spacing with UITextView?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

Do you have any ideas about line spacing with UITextView? I cannot apply it. Below it is my code.

```
import UIKit

class DetailViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var itemTextView: UITextView!
    var txtString: String?
    var txtTitleBar:String?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //navigationController?.navigationItem.title = "Love"
        self.title = txtTitleBar

        //self.tabBarController?.navigationItem.title = "My Title"
        itemTextView.text = txtString
        itemTextView.font = UIFont(name: "Arial-Regular", size:20)
        itemTextView.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 25)
        (itemTextView.font?.lineHeight)! * 5
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: What is `(itemTextView.font?.lineHeight)! * 5` supposed to do?

Comment: it applies line spacing but cannot effect

Comment: No, that does not apply line spacing. You read the line spacing value and multiply that value by 5. But you do nothing with the result.

Comment: Now it is working with this: let style = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
style.lineSpacing = 20
let attributes = [NSParagraphStyleAttributeName : style]
textView.attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: txtString, attributes: attributes)

Comment: You should accept the appropriate answer instead of posting "thank you".

Comment: Please tell me detail how can I do brother?

Comment: Click the checkmark to the left of the answer that you feel best answered your question.

Comment: When I click on it, it show the message :  Thank for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation..........

Comment: You need to click on the checkmark, not the triangle.

Comment: now I can do it. Thank you so much brother.

Comment: the ONLY WAY now is this:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/75997965/294884

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You need to use an attributed string and assign a paragraph style. For example:

```
let style = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
style.lineSpacing = 20
let attributes = [NSParagraphStyleAttributeName : style]
textView.attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: txtString, attributes: attributes)
```

See this SO answer for more details on attributed string usage: [How do I make an attributed string using Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24666515/how-do-i-make-an-attributed-string-using-swift)

---

Note, as of 2022 you do not need to use an attributed string. You can use `.typingAttributes` if preferred.

Comment: Okay, but how do I keep the text the user is entering in the same paragraph style? Do I have to perform your code on every textFieldDidChange: event?

Comment: @linus_hologram Having the same problem did you have any luck with this?

Comment: @TomWicks I ended up using this code with every textFieldDidChange: event. As far as I know, this is the only option

Comment: Use `textView.typingTextAttributes`. This will allow you to set the default attributes.

Comment: doesn't work at all. the ONLY way now, 2023, is this stackoverflow.com/a/75997965/294884

Answer (score 5):

**Xcode 9.2 Swift 4**

```
let style = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
style.lineSpacing = 0
let attributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.paragraphStyle : style]
txtViewAbout.attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: txtViewAbout.text, attributes: attributes)
```

Answer (score 4):

**Xcode 10.1 Swift 4.2**

```
let style = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
style.lineSpacing = 19
let attributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle: style]
textView.attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: model.text, attributes: attributes)
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `typingAttributes` will make sure that the attributes apply to new text that the user enters.

```
let style = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
style.lineSpacing = 10
let attributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle : style]
textView.typingAttributes = attributes
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let contentTextView: UITextView = {
    let textView = UITextView()

    textView.backgroundColor = .clear

    // Custom style
    let style = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    style.lineSpacing = 10
    let attributes = [
        NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle: style,
        NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white,
        NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)
    ]
    textView.typingAttributes = attributes

    return textView
}()
```

> This dictionary contains the attribute keys (and corresponding values) to apply to newly typed text. When the text view’s selection changes, the contents of the dictionary are cleared automatically.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextview/1618629-typingattributes

Answer (score 0):

*Swift 5.7, iOS 16.0*

Here's an extension to provide a `textView.lineSpacing` getter & setter:

```
extension UITextView {
    
    /// Gets & Sets line spacing via `typingAttributes`.
    /// Preserves defined `style` and `textColor`.
    var lineSpacing: CGFloat {
        get {
            if let style = typingAttributes[NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle] {
                return (style as! NSMutableParagraphStyle).lineSpacing
            }
            return 0
        }
        set {
            let style = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
            style.lineSpacing = newValue
            let attributes = [
                NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle: style,
                NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: textColor,
                NSAttributedString.Key.font: font
            ]
            typingAttributes = attributes as [NSAttributedString.Key : Any]
        }
    }
}
```

It can be used when initialising the `UITextView` like so:

```
textView.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18)
textView.textColor = UIColor.purple
textView.lineSpacing = 3.4
```

Comment: doesn't work at all. the ONLY way now, 2023, is this https://stackoverflow.com/a/75997965/294884