# iOS 11: UITextView typingAttributes reset when typing

Tags: ios, uitextview, ios11

I use `typingAttributes` to set a new font. On **iOS 10**, everything works, but on **iOS 11**, first typed character is correct, but then attributes are being reset to the previous ones, and the second character is typed with the previous font. Is this a bug? Can I fix it somehow?

Answer (score 12):

## Why this happened:

Apple updated `typingAttributes` since iOS 11

> This dictionary contains the attribute keys (and corresponding values) to apply to newly typed text. When the text view’s selection changes, the contents of the dictionary are cleared automatically.

## How to fix it:

@Serdnad's code works but it will skip the first character. Here is my finding after trying everything that I can possibly think of

**1. If you just want one universal typing attribute for your text view**

Simply set the typing attribute once in this delegate method and you are all set with this single universal font

```
func textViewShouldBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView) -> Bool {
    //Set your typing attributes here
    textView.typingAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor.rawValue: UIColor.blue, NSAttributedStringKey.font.rawValue: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17)]
    return true
}
```

[image]

**2. In my case, a Rich Text Editor with attributes changeinge all the times:**

In this case, I do have to set typing attributes each and every time after entering anything. Thank you iOS 11 for this update!

However, instead of setting that in `textViewDidChange` method, doing it in `shouldChangeTextIn` method works better since it gets called before entering characters into the text view.

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
    textView.typingAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor.rawValue: UIColor.blue, NSAttributedStringKey.font.rawValue: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17)]
    return true
}
```

[image]

Comment: @user2296278 Sadly, I have removed the editor.... It won't work since the html generated by iOS from attributted text is not usable on Android devices

Comment: ok thanks I want this editor because I can't find any text  editor in swift 4  if you recreated or use GitHub or you can help me send me a message please

Comment: We're solving it through a sort of Hack.  See: https://github.com/wordpress-mobile/AztecEditor-iOS/blob/develop/Aztec/Classes/TextKit/TextView.swift#L580

Comment: Be careful, this solution doesn't work for iOS12 and "Automatic Strong Passwords". The app just freezes forever

Comment: **while this old answer has critical and awesome information, unfortunately many details have changed.  I've put in a new answer for 2023**

Answer (score 9):

Had issues with memory usage while using `typingAttributes`

This solution worked:

```
textField.defaultTextAttributes = yourAttributes // (set in viewDidLoad / setupUI)
```

What was the problem with using typingAttributes: at some point in time, the memory usage went up and never stopped and caused the app to freeze.

Comment: I didn't have memory issues, but this is the only answer that worked for me. Thank you! :)

Comment: this solution is worked for me.

Comment: **There is no such thing as "defaultTextAttributes" on a UITextView**

Comment: The question is about UITextView but this answer only applies to UITextField.

Answer (score 7):

I ran into the same issue and eventually solved it by setting typingAttributes again after every edit.

**Swift 3**

```
func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
    NotesTextView.typingAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.blue, NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17)]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## 2023, the only way:

Note that previous solutions such as `textViewShouldBeginEditing` simply don't work.  You must now do these two:

```
func textViewDidBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
    _tvHassles()
    outsideDelegate?.textViewDidBeginEditing?(textView)
}

func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
    _tvHassles()
    outsideDelegate?.textViewDidChange?(textView)
}

func _tvHassles() {
    
    let ps = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    ps.lineSpacing = 3.0 // (means specifically "extra points between lines")
    
    typingAttributes = [
        
        NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.green,
        NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont. .. your font,
        NSAttributedString.Key.tracking: 0.88,
        NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle: ps
    ]
}
```

It's utterly absurd that this much needs to be done to set the font in a text entry box, but, there you have it.

**Note that of course, it would be insanity in real-life programming to do all this in a view controller. "setting a font" is not vc material, it's view material.**

So in practice, do this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75997746/294884 and put it in your text view class.

Answer (score 0):

From iOS 11, Apple clear the attributes after every character.

> When the text view’s selection changes, the contents of the dictionary are cleared automatically.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextview/1618629-typingattributes