# Control Line Spacing in UITextView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3

[image]

I'm trying to remove line spaces in an UITextView but can't seem to figure it out.
I tried textContainer.lineFragmentPadding and NSLineBreakMode, but with no luck.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42966381/cant-apply-line-spacing-with-uitextview

Comment: Yes. but then text.font = UIFont(name: "AvenirNextCondensed-Regular", size: font_size) stops working and the font size is off. And if I move the UIFont after the style, then the line space is off again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `NSAttributedString` instead of `String` like this:

```
let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Your text")

// *** Create instance of `NSMutableParagraphStyle`
let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()

// *** set LineSpacing property in points ***
paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = 2 // Whatever line spacing you want in points

// *** Apply attribute to string ***
attributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle, value:paragraphStyle, range:NSMakeRange(0, attributedString.length))
if let font = UIFont(name: "AvenirNextCondensed-Regular", size: font_size) {
    attributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.font, value: font, range: NSMakeRange(0, attributedString.length))
}

// *** Set Attributed String to your label ***
textView.attributedText = attributedString
```

Comment: Thank you. I can control the line space like this. but as soon as I add style, the font size is off. text.font = UIFont(name: "AvenirNextCondensed-Regular", size: font_size) doesnt work anymore.