# Swift Multiple Label in one strikethroughStyle

Tags: swift, uilabel, uistackview

I try to implement strikethroughStyle to labels. I use this below code for one label. But I want to draw one line for this two different label as in picture . (I use `stackview` for these labels)

Thanks in advance.

```
let attributedString2 = NSMutableAttributedString(string: self.productDetailView.productOldLastPriceLabel.text ?? "")
attributedString2.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.strikethroughStyle, value: 2, range: NSMakeRange(0, attributedString2.length))
self.productDetailView.productOldLastPriceLabel.attributedText = attributedString2
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the below code to manage strikethrough with different font size of text. You can modify the range as per your requirement

```
let str1 = "16230"
let str2 = "63455333"

let dateText = NSMutableAttributedString.init(string: "\(str1)\(str2)")
    dateText.setAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 34, weight: UIFont.Weight.bold),
                            NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.black, NSAttributedString.Key.strikethroughStyle: 2],
                           range: NSMakeRange(0, str1.count))
    dateText.setAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 34, weight: UIFont.Weight.thin),
                            NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.black, NSAttributedString.Key.strikethroughStyle: 1],
                           range: NSMakeRange(str1.count,str2.count))

    // set the attributed string to the UILabel object
    deadline_lbl.attributedText = dateText
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I dont know the length of the string

Comment: Without the length how will you know what font size to apply yo what text. Can you share some code for me to check

Comment: I use two uilabel . I parse the json string with decimal part and Int part . Then I merge these labels with uistackview

Comment: Hi I have modified the code so you can understand. Text for 2 strings added to datetext with the fontsize and strike through you require

Comment: I got this issue : Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: 'NSMutableRLEArray replaceObjectsInRange:withObject:length:: Out of bounds'

Comment: your range for text is going out for range. share your text for me to review

Comment: Please check now have edited the code.. works fine. Please mark it correct if useful.

Comment: there is a single text label which shows both text appended together.

Comment: Yes I know. Also you didnt draw str2.

Comment: It draws whole label. But I change the textsize for str2 and the line is seperated. Like as in the question last picture

Comment: yes because the strike line will depend on the font, is size, weight etc.

Answer (score -1):

You can use just one label to write all text istead of two adjancted texts. And use different fonts for its parts and use strikethroughStyle for all text.

[This link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32269975/6608199) could help you to do this